# Array of pictureboxes and resource images

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Hey all i have the following code:

```
Dim radarStrengthImages() As PictureBox = ({imgRadar_Strength1, imgRadar_Strength2, imgRadar_Strength3, imgRadar_Strength4, imgRadar_Strength5, imgRadar_Strength6, imgRadar_Strength7, imgRadar_Strength8})
Dim radarStrengthResourcesON() As Bitmap = ({My.Resources.radarON_16, My.Resources.radarON_17, My.Resources.radarON_18, My.Resources.radarON_19, My.Resources.radarON_20, My.Resources.radarON_21, My.Resources.radarON_22, My.Resources.radarON_23})
Dim radarStrengthResourcesOFF() As Bitmap = ({My.Resources.radar_16, My.Resources.radar_17, My.Resources.radar_18, My.Resources.radar_19, My.Resources.radar_20, My.Resources.radar_21, My.Resources.radar_22, My.Resources.radar_23})
```

The **imgRadar_StrengthX** is the name of the pictureboxes on the form itself and **My.Resources.radar_XX** is the image for the pictureboxes.

However when i use this code:

```
Dim intX As Integer = 0

Do Until intX = 8
    radarStrengthImages(intX).Image = radarStrengthResourcesON(intX)
    intX += 1
Loop
```

I get an error of:

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

and that happens on this like:

```
radarStrengthImages(intX).Image = radarStrengthResourcesON(intX)
```

Comment: when you debug, mouse over the error, which one is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of code can't work, initialization order is always an important detail.  The variables you use don't get a value until *after* the InitializeComponent() method runs.  But the arrays are initialized *before* that happens.  So you just initialize them with Nothing, nada, zippo.  "Object reference not set" is the zippo exception you'll get.

You'll have to do it later, that requires moving the initializer for the array into the constructor.  Generic syntax for a sample form with textboxes:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim boxes As TextBox()

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        boxes = New TextBox() {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

issue is this array start at index 0 and you have 8 items

change the loop to

```
   Do Until intX = 7
```

and it should now work

or if the array will change in time, use a variable to handle the max

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim intX As Integer = 0

    Dim test(7) As Integer '8 item
    Dim max = test.Length - 1

    Do Until intX = max
        intX += 1
    Loop

    Console.WriteLine("intX: " & intX)
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You really ought to explain how the loop could be entered with IntX = 8.